# passing $(this) with "var _this"

Tags: jquery, this

Got his code, easy task:

1.Click list item
2.get list item values 
3.put in input
4.change them manually
5.save them back to the list item per klick

After clicking multiple list items and saving them, the values are changed for all the list items that have been klicked on before, too.

Seems like "_this" is saving all the connections.

Any idea how to make this work? Big thanks!

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="bar"></a>
        <span class="name">Name1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="bar"></a>
        <span class="name">Name2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="bar"></a>
        <span class="name">Name3</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<input id="editName">
<a id="save"></a>


$("#foo").on('click', '.bar', function() {      

    _this = $(this);
    edit(_this);
    });

function edit(_this) {

    var name = _this.parent().children(".name").text();
    $("#editName").val(name);

    $("#save").click( function() {
        _this.parent().find(".name").text(  $("#edit input#editName").val()  );
        });

    };
```

Comment: You're finding by classname, which will effect every class `.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time edit(_this) is invoked you bind a new delegate and after let say 3 times this method called... next time you will press the '#save' you will get three different invocations of this delegate.
to solve this you can add a variable that will get the _this value and hold it:

```
var _thisglobal='';
```

get out the biding function from edit(_this) and use the global value _thisglobal instead of _this:

```
function edit(_this) {
    _thisglobal=_this;
    var name = _this.parent().children(".name").text();
    $("#editName").val(name);



    }; 

$("#save").click( function() {
        _thisglobal.parent().find(".name").text(  $("#edit input#editName").val()  );
        });
```